# Variation and Quadratic variation of $\int B(s) ds$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

Consider the Stochastic process $X(t) = \int_o^t B(s)ds$.

We know that $\int_o^t B(s)ds = \int_o^t (t - s)dB(s)$. This implies that quadratic variation of X,
$<X,X>(t) = t^3/3$.

On the other hand, we know that $|B(s,w)|$ is bounded by $M(w)$ on $[0,t]$ for almost all $w$. This implies that variation of X(t), $FV(X(t,w)) < M(w)*t$ on $[0,t]$. This implies that quadratic variation of $X(t)$ is $0$ almost everywhere. How is this possible?

Comment: I guess $B$ is the standard brownian motion, but what is $M(\omega)$?

Comment: How did you compute the quadratic variation the first time?

Comment: M(w) is the bound on $B(s,w)$ for $s \in [0,t]$

Comment: I computed the quadratic variation of $\int_0^t (t - s)dB(s)$ using the standard result $<\int_0^t \xi(s) dB(s), \int_0^t \xi(s) dB(s)> = \int_0^t \xi(s)^2 ds$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second one is correct, the quadratic variation of $X$ is $0$ almost everywhere.  It looks like you computed $\langle X,X \rangle_t = \int_0^t (t-s)^2ds$ the first time to get $\frac 13 t^3$, but this doesn't work because the formula that $\langle \int_0^t h(s)dB(s),\int_0^t h(s)dB(s) \rangle  = \int_0^t h(s)^2ds$ requires that $h$ depend only on $s$.  Since $(t-s)$ also depends on $t$, this will not give the correct quadratic variation.